# how to load filename to include from defined variable

Tags: templates, variables, pug

I have a variable, which defines a template name to be included:

```
- var content = 'content-css.jade'
```

then i want to use this variable value to define which file should be included:

```
include #{content}
```

but jade interprets this as it is, so it look for file named `#{content}` instead of `content-css.jade`.

Here is entire code:

```
include ./partials/head.jade

- var content = 'content-css.jade'
body
  .fw-layout
    .fw-topbar.sticky topbar
    .fw-middle
      .fw-sides
        .fw-sideleft
          .fw-inner.sticky
        .fw-content
          .fw-inner
            .fw-page
              include ./partials/grid-page.jade
```

Then `grid-page.jade` has it's own html structure

```
... grid-page static header ...

... grid-page dynamic content ...
include #{content}

... grid-page static footer ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok i have found an answer, since Jade does not support variables inside include I have used a mixin instead:

```
mixin content
  include ./partials/content-css.jade
```

then include with

```
+content
```